# Do residents through golden visa programs pay income taxes if they don't stay in the country for more than 183 days?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, latvia

For example, Latvia offers a residency by investment program, and I was wondering whether it matters if you stay in the country for more than 183 days in order to pay the taxes?  Or are you already considered a "resident" and have to pay the taxes (worldwide income if resident, income from Latvian sources only if non resident) whether you stay in the country or not? In other words, does getting a temporary residence permit automatically makes you a tax resident?